# Can copper vessel be boiled?

Tags: water

I have the habit of boiling water before drinking.

I am planning to buy a copper dispenser.

In this context, I am getting the following doubts:

1. Can I boil water using copper water dispenser?
2. Is it okay to store boiled water insider copper water dispenser? If (1) is not recommended.

Comment: Is your dispenser lined with stainless steel ?

Comment: this seems overkill, why can't you just use a stainless steel kettle (or an electric kettle0 ?

Answer (score 1):

For a recurrent use in the kitchen, copper must be lined. This is done since long time.
If you boil water for a safer consumption or to reduce the smell of disinfectants*, then definitely you should buy a copper boiler only if lined.

*otherwise don't boil it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility of corrosion. Any copper ions in drinking water are bad. Copper is generally toxic ; it is used to keep ship hulls free of barnacles , etc. That is why old copper pans are tin coated and new copper pans are clad with stainless steel ( I have recently seen new pans with an apparent tin coating ).  The corrosiveness of the water depends on its composition , city water in plumbing is relatively benign. But when you add foods, many contain acids, etc ,that can release copper ions( corrosion), so bare copper cookware would be risky. Your water may pick up a trace of copper , and over time it could reach a harmful level in your body.

Comment: Copper is also an essential micronutrient that aids iron uptake. A deficiency creates similar symptoms to anemia. It is entirely false to say that "any copper ions in drinking water are bad".

Comment: A normal diet will provide  trace elements Mg, Se, Zn, Cu, Mn, Cr, and Mo. A physician should be consulted before deliberately increasing ingestion of any of them.